# How would I compare the contents of a 1D char array against a 2D char array while ignoring case sensitivity?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d

Say my 1D char array looks like:

> [E, A, D, C, C]

and my 2D char array looks like:

> [ [E, A, D, B, C], [d, a, d, e, c], [b, a, , e, a] ]

Here is what I tried to do:

```
public void calculateStatistics(char [] correctAnswers, String [] studentName, char [][] studentAnswers, int fillLvl2, int fillLvl3)
{
    int [] marks = new int [3];
    double average = 0; 
    int totalSum = 0;
    int sum;
    for(int row = 0; row < correctAnswers.length; row++)
    {
        sum = 0; 
        for(int col = 0; col < studentAnswers.length; col++)
        {
            if(studentAnswers[row][col].equals(correctAnswers[col]))
            {
                sum++; 
                totalSum += totalSum;
            }
        }
        marks[row] = sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it correctly, you can change the portion of the code where you compare both strings to:

```
String studentAnswer = String.valueOf(studentAnswers[row][col]);
String correctAnswer = String.valueOf(correctAnswers[col]);
if(studentAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(correctAnswer))
{
    sum++; 
    totalSum += totalSum;
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying that car cannot be dereferenced

Comment: I suppose the error was "char cannot ... ".  I edited the answer i gave you.

Comment: Would I just declare those String within the for loop? I still get an error

Comment: After the second loop yes.

Answer (score 0):

To work with chars, and avoid any AutoBoxing to Character or String, you could use a helper method like this:

```
static final int convertToLower = 'a' - 'A'; 
boolean isCharEqualsIgnoreCase(char c1, char c2) {
    if (c1 <= 'Z')
        c1 += convertToLower;
    if (c2 <= 'Z')
        c2 += convertToLower;
    return c1 == c2;
}
```

Test cases:

```
isCharEqualsIgnoreCase('a', 'a'); // true
isCharEqualsIgnoreCase('A', 'A'); // true
isCharEqualsIgnoreCase('a', 'A'); // true
isCharEqualsIgnoreCase('A', 'a'); // true
isCharEqualsIgnoreCase('A', 'b'); // false
```

Or, use autoboxing: one example is

```
char c = 'c';
char C = 'C';

Character.valueOf(c).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Character.valueOf(C).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a character to lower case use `Character.toLowerCase()` method. Your if statement would then look as follows:

```
if(Character.toLowerCase(studentAnswers[row][col]) == correctAnswers[col])
```

Your code would then look as follows(outside of a function):

```
char [] correctAnswers = {'a','b','c','a','b','c'};
String [] studentName = {"Sam", "Cathy", "Jensen"};
char [][] studentAnswers = {{'d','B','c','a','b','c'},
                            {'a','a','a','a','b','a'},
                            {'c','b','a','A','B','C'}};
int [] marks = new int [3];
double average = 0; 
int totalSum = 0;
int sum;
for(int row = 0; row < studentAnswers.length; row++)
{
    sum = 0; 
    for(int col = 0; col < correctAnswers.length; col++)
    {
        if(Character.toLowerCase(studentAnswers[row][col]) == correctAnswers[col])
        {
            sum++; 
            totalSum += totalSum;
        }
    }
        marks[row] = sum;
        System.out.println("Students Mark: " + marks[row]);
    }
```

Program Outputs:

```
Students Mark: 5
Students Mark: 3
Students Mark: 4
```

Comment: But this would always return false because the two arrays are pointing to different references no?

Comment: @Mcbever what do you mean by pointing to different references?

Comment: The contents in each array point to different indexes so the == operand would always return false in this case

Comment: @Mcbever I tested the code and it worked as expected?

Comment: It’ll compile, but the memory location of each index in the arrays point to different locations.

Comment: I ran the program it compiled and gave the correct test scores, therefore it doesn't seem to be a problem? would you like me to post the two versions of code it tested in my answer?

Comment: Hmmm alright I guess you're right. I don't know why, but I get an array out of bounds exception when I try to store the marks in the array and print it now

Comment: @Mcbever sorry I forgot to mention that I changed what row and col correspond to now. Row < studentAnswers.length rather than < correctAnswers.length. Try that

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to compare characters in a case-insensitive manner is this:

```
Character.toLowerCase(c1) == Character.toLowerCase(c2)
```

Alternatively you can do this:

```
(c1 == c2) || (Character.isLowerCase(c1) ? (c1 == Character.toLowerCase(c2)) : (c1 == Character.toUpperCase(c2)))
```

Your mistake was that you tried to call `equals`, which is a method for objects and the characters you intend to compare are not objects, they are primitive variables.